# How to open dialog bog of each row in jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have multiple rows of table in jsp. On click of button of particular button  of row, i have to open the dialog box dynamically.
How can it be done in jquery?

Comment: You need to show table markup!

Comment: Thank you. <table>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Button</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Button</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table> i will have multiple rows like this. On click of button of each td of  each row, dialog box should be opened dynamically.